# does heat capacity ratio, i.e cp/cv depends on pressure if ideal gas assumption is considered?

Tags: thermodynamics

cp/cv does change with a change in temperature. But does it changes with pressure too if the temperature is kept constant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For an ideal gaz, $cp$ and $cv$ are independant of pressure and so is the ratio. (First and second Joule law).

Comment: could you please explain how so... with equations

Comment: You can find the proof at :https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/405822/internal-energy-of-an-ideal-gas-independent-of-any-thermodynamic-variable-at-con

Comment: Does that mean that for a real gas, say air it is not constant? I landed here trying to figure out if the speed of sounds would show (minor) variations with changing pressure.